# Using [FromUri] and [FromBody] simultaneously to bind a complex Web Api method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, dto, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am using request and response models to encapsulate data that needs to be passed to methods in my ASP.NET Web Api, using `[FromUri]` and `[FromBody]` when necessary.

There are instances, however, in which I would like to use both Uri and Body to populate the properties of my request model. An example would be in updating a user, where the `UserId` should be passed in the Uri, but the data to update would be passed in the body content. My desired implementation would look something like this:

**Model**:

```
public class UpdateUserRequestModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

**Api Method**:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Update/{UserId}")]
// PUT: api/Users/Update/user@domain.net
public async Task UpdateUserAsync(UpdateUserRequestModel model)
{
    // Method logic
}
```

I would like the property `UserId` to be obtained `[FromUri]`, but the rest to be obtained `[FromBody]`, all while keeping everything all parameters in a single object. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, but if it's not, you can always write your own custom serializer.

Comment: A `HTTPPUT` allows this.But you need to pass both the `uri` parameter and the `body`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh How would I design my syntax to support that, though? Keep in mind that I am trying to populate a properties of a single input parameter from different sources.

Comment: accept two parameters at your action, pass the `id` property via `uri`, and the whole object via `body`.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I am currently using that approach in my code. What I want to do is maintain that level of functionality, but transfer the `id` property and put it inside the `model` parameter,

Comment: Not sure how to achieve that.

Comment: You could create a model binder or HttpParameterBinding. Deserialize the body to you object and the read userid from the path and apply to model. See https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: It's interesting that good-old MVC can do this out of the box but not Web API.

Answer (score 0):

Not the cleanest solution but it should work:

```
[HttpPut]
[Route("Update/{UserId}")]
// PUT: api/Users/Update/user@domain.net
public async Task UpdateUserAsync(UpdateUserRequestModel model, int UserId)
{
    model.UserId = UserId;
}
```